# CoordinatorLayout positioning

Tags: android, header, android-coordinatorlayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/group_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mysay_group_placeholder"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/group_image"
                android:background="#99000000"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/group_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Group name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/visibility_rule"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/group_title"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/public_group"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/recent_questions"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/manage_contacts"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_vote_white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/manage_contacts"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/members_count_text_view"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/group_members_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/members_count_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <com.mysayapplication.mysayapp.mysay.ui.MySayHeader
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@color/divider" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/closed_group_full_state"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/tab_questions" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/label"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/archive_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/empty_questions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/no_questions_icon" />


                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/toolbar_image_tint" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/answers_empty_state_msg"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ask_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_dark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

i don't want the header (@+id/header) to collapse when i scroll the recycler view.

if i place it outside the CollapsingToolbarLayout the layout won't collapse anymore and if i put it outside the AppBarLayout it will be covered with the CollapsingToolbarLayout when i scroll.

My target is to collapse the CollapsingToolbarLayout under the header in a way that the header is always visible.

Comment: By header, You mean the red color which you highlighted the area or the picture which shows under the `Toolbar`?

Comment: the highlighted area

Comment: Well you’re not using any Toolbars there...Use Toolbar then make it not collapsable by pinning it in there...